# How to have application code uses Gson and let Actuator uses Jackson?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson, spring-boot-actuator

I understand that by using Actuator then we must use Jackson instead of Gson:

- [Spring Boot Actuator dependency on Jackson prevents usage of GSON](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2247)
- [can spring actuator use gson or other json tools instead of strongly depends on jackson?](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13194)

When the preferred json mapper is Gson then some Actuator endpoints will be broken. Steps to reproduce:

1. [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/), dependencies: Web, Actuator. Generate project
2. Edit `pom.xml`, add gson dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
       <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Edit `application.properties`

   ```
   management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
   spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper=gson
   ```
4. GET `/actuator/beans`, it will encounter 500 Internal Server Error with log:

   ```
   WARN 14692 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoker.cache.CachingOperationInvokerAdvisor. Forgot to register a type adapter?; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class: org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoker.cache.CachingOperationInvokerAdvisor. Forgot to register a type adapter?
   ```
5. GET `/actuator/mapping`, it will encounter another error as well.

How to have application code uses Gson, and still let Actuator uses Jackson?

Comment: Any updates on your question here? I'm facing the same issues. Thx in advance for your answer. Cheers